# User redirection to the application root path in UI5

Tags: redirect, sapui5, http-redirect

From an UI5 application I send a request to a server-side via Fetch API and on the server-side I send a response with a redirect to the UI5-app root directory:

```js
import {constants as httpConstants} from "http2";

res.statusCode = httpConstants.HTTP_STATUS_MOVED_PERMANENTLY;
res.header("Location", "/");
```

The UI5 application gets the response but browser doesn't redirect an user. The only way to redirect an user to the app root is:

```js
sap.m.URLHelper.redirect("/", false);
```

Is there any way to force a browser to redirect an user to an UI5-app root without using `sap.m.URLHelper`? I want to make as hard as possible the prevention of redirection, e.g. with a help of browser's DevTools.

Comment: Why? You have to assume that at any point any user can manually enter any possible route in the address bar and therefore access any view of your application.

Comment: @Marc, ideally, I would like to separate an UI5 app views from a login view, so if an user has no valid cookies, then he should not be able to open any view except login one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UI5 routing is currently using the # part (called fragment or anchor).
This is client side part of the URL and unknown to the server.

You have maybe luck with some backend technologies and browser, but in general this will not work.

As DevTools can manipulate anyways anything… Make sure backend is secure. UI can always be change by the user, no matter what obscure security measurements you make up.

Answer (score -2):

You can try using the HashChanger to route it back to login page!
Once your validation from server is done, use below code!

```
jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.core.routing.HashChanger");
sap.ui.core.routing.HashChanger.getInstance().replaceHash("");
```